# show uploaded image in page.tpl

Tags: theming, media

I created a content type and added an image filed (machine name: field_theme_image). 
Then, I've added a new content in this content type and uploaded an image. 
Now, I want this image to be shown in "page.tpl.php", so that this can be seen in all the pages. Please let me know how this can be done done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have rather used a block and put it in a region, so to show up on all pages. This would keep my tpl fiels clean and also will allow me show/hide block on some pages.